# Why cookie is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to get cookie via getInitialProps in main component _app.ts, but cookie is undefined, code:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({req}: NextPageContext) => {
            console.log(req.headers.cookie) //undefined
}
```

P.S using next.js

Answer (score 0):

Because getIntialProps runs in server you can get coockies in both server side and client side using this package [cookies-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next)